# Docusign go live review failed with message: Have made at least 20 successful API calls

Tags: docusignapi

From my demo account.i made 25 transactions and all the docs was sign and completed i am getting integrator key Review status failed Review Result: Have made at least 20 successful API calls. What is mean ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPwng.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check (accept) the best answer to your own questions. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1):

If go-live is not passing, and the tool says that you have not made 20 test API calls, then check:

1. Did you use the authorize token generator tool to obtain an access token for your app? Those tokens can only be used during development. You need to use an OAuth flow for production and the go-live check.
2. Did you use the API explorer or the DocuSign web tool for your test API calls? You need to use your own integration key with your software.
3. There can be rare circumstances where the go-live check doesn't see your API test calls because their trace records have not been transferred over (yet) to the DocuSign analytics system. If only some of your API calls are listed in the go-live log, then this may be the issue. Wait 10 minutes and re-run the go-live review process. No need to re-do your API calls in this case.

Comment: is the integration key necessary for all API calls? If a real access token is generated in the demo account, why do the API calls not show?

Comment: Go-live checks the behavior of your application as denoted by its integration key (client id). So the only API calls checked by go-live are those where the call's access token is associated with the integration key under test.

Comment: When you say "access token is associated with the integration key", do you mean using our integration key we've obtained user consent and authorization tokens, so those are associated? If so, that is what we're doing but seeing nothing in our dashboard. See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65203884/docusign-api-calls-do-not-show-on-demo-dashboard

Comment: I got the answer on the question I posted. It is because we are an ISV and were testing using user accounts not associated with our account. For the dashboard, only API calls for users on your account will show up.