# DocuSign API calls do not show on demo dashboard

Tags: docusignapi

We are using DocuSign API via demo account for signatures. We are using Authorization Code Grant workflow and are obtaining authorizations in our demo workflow. So real access tokens are being used.

But no API calls are being shown in our demo account API Dashboard.

[image]

But I can see via our monitoring tool we are hitting DocuSign. Plus the flow of the integration is all working properly.

[image]

Why are the calls not showing up? This is affecting our ability to proceed with app review process.

**Notes**

- The model we're using is ISV
- We use Authorization Code Grant workflow
- We obtain user authorization for users outside of our account since we are an ISV

My question is similar to [this one but we are using real access tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61930301/docusign-go-live-review-failed-with-message-have-made-at-least-20-successful-ap).

Comment: Sometimes there are delays of 5-10 minutes. Can you double check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information in the dashboard may be outdate by 10-20 minutes as it takes some time for the process to get the API requests to the dashboard.
Please allow for a few minutes of delay and check the dashboard a bit later if you have new API calls you're trying to view in the dashboard.

Also, for ISVs, the portal only shows your own account. You must make the API calls from your own account that was used to create the IK. If you use a different account - it would not show in the developer dashboard.

Comment: We've had this running in our dev environment as we've been building it out for about 2 weeks now. The dashboard shows nothing for the past 30 days.

Comment: is is possible you have more than one account?

Comment: at this point the dashboard only shows API calls made by the same account that is logged into it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. We created the account - I specifically created the developer account. I created the integration key from this dashboard. We are using that integration key. Shouldn't our API calls show up in this dashboard? I edited post, we are an ISV so user authorization doesn't come from our users.

Comment: that's the issue. Let me update the answer.

Comment: That was it. I did one using my user attached to our account and I see it logged to the dashboard. Thank you for the clarification!